# Android interfacing with phone with a broken screen

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen, android-pc

Screen is 100% dead black.

What are your options? What can you do from the PC with a phone with a broken screen?

I can find plethora of software promising you to do all kind of magic, but half of them most likely malware, adware, bloatware:

https://www.coolmuster.com/android/top-3-android-repair-software.html

Good news is I had USB debugging enabled before the screen broke.
The phone works perfectly tho. I can hear the alarms, email notifications, notification sounds from other apps, the PC recognize it.

Is there a software which makes it possible to show the screen of the phone on the PC when connected through USB cable???

Comment: Is this a phone or tablet, if its a tablet you may have a micro hdmi port that you can go out to an external monitor just by plugging it in.  If its a phone I don't really know what functionality you have unless you state the brand and model.

Comment: Samsung A41 no hdmi just USB-C.

Comment: Do you have a Samsung Multi-port Adapter?  The cost 30 to 100 dollars depending on where you purchase from, or a generic off aliexpress for $15

Comment: You plug a HDMI cable into the adapter

Answer (score 5):

If you have a working adb connection you can use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to mirror the phone screen to a connected PC or Mac.

Scrcpy is an open source tool. The only problem that can arise is that typical scrcpy distributions contain an older version of adb which then conflicts with an already installed version.

But besides of that scrcpy is a perfect tool for phones with dead screen.

Comment: Device unauthorized man :( I can use the screen and even without seeing I know where the Allow button is because I can mtp off pictures the same way but it doesn't work in your case it keep saying it's unauthorized.